# Qual a origem da palavra "beque" (ou back, ou beck) significando um cigarro de maconha?

Tags: etimologia, estrangeirismos

Em várias regiões do Brasil a palavra "beque" (ou beck, também back) é usada para denominar um cigarro de maconha, como na frase:

`- André, me passe logo este beque, por favor.`

Um [comentário no twitter](https://twitter.com/luxgabs/status/1317087847661391873) indica que viria do termo inglês `backwoods blunt`, que seria um baseado enrolado numa folha de tabaco. Normalmente estes são mais grossos e maiores do que a média e isso pode indicar que o termo beque se difere do termo "fininho" por implicitamente indicar um cigarro maior e mais grosso.

**Alguém tem alguma fonte mais concreta que corrobore ou contradiga essa hipótese?**

Comment: Não sei se é novidade para ti, mas cá vai: (fumar) *beque* já aparece na imprensa em [1997](https://books.google.pt/books?id=cy0EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT82&dq=%22fumando+um+beque%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl1Nbfxr3sAhXT7eAKHd2PBsYQ6AEwBHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22fumando%20um%20beque%22&f=false), e [*beck* em 1999](https://books.google.pt/books?id=E21aAAAAMAAJ&q=%22fumando+um+beck%22&dq=%22fumando+um+beck%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi049yu3b3sAhWq8uAKHcnODngQ6AEwB3oECAcQAg).

Comment: Desconheço a origem, mas não foi em nenhum país de língua inglesa, já que neles a palavra `beck` não é usada para se referir a maconha. Como essa palavra pode se referir a fumaça (um `becker` tem esse nome em parte porque é um recipiente usado para aquecer líquidos até eles evaporarem ou virarem fumaça), provavelmente algum brasileiro com conhecimento da língua inglesa adotou essa palavra, como referência simbólica à fumaça que sai do cigarro de maconha, então outras pessoas gostaram da palavra e também a adotaram, o que por fim consolidou o uso dessa gíria.

Comment: "Bec" em Francês (se pronuncia como "beck") significa bico (como bico de pássaro mas também o bico que fazemos com a boca quando beijamos ou quando estamos chateados), mas não sei até que ponto isso poderia ter influenciado a gíria...

Comment: @Yuri: Isso e um **beaker** não um becker....

Comment: @Lambie A palavra original é alemã: `bäcker` (ou `baecker`), que significa "cozinhar", "aquecer", "cozedor", "aquecedor", "padeiro" etc. `Becker` é morfologicamente inglesa, porém usada no Brasil. `Beaker` também é morfologicamente inglesa, e é a forma que se consolidou nos países de língua inglesa.

Comment: Não vale a pena tentar mudar o que você disse: "Como essa palavra pode se referir a fumaça (um becker tem esse nome em parte porque é um recipiente usado para aquecer líquidos até eles evaporarem ou virarem fumaça)." **beaker** Google dic. etimologia:  "**Middle English (in the sense ‘large drinking container’): from Old Norse bikarr, perhaps based on Greek bikos ‘drinking bowl**’"

Comment: Qual 1997? [Beck começou em 1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beck#Early_performances_and_first_releases_(1988%E2%80%931993))... 

Answer (score 3):

Não fumo esse negócio, mas na minha adolescência, eu ouvia o termo pronunciado como "bégue", não "béque".
Achei que fosse porque você pega a palavra `bagulho`, (da gíria, "fumar um bagulho"), abrevia para `bag` e pronuncia como se fosse inglês ("bégue").
Com o passar do tempo, fui ouvindo cada vez mais *béque* e não *bégue*.

Comment: user11907, quando é que foi a tua adolescência? Quando andamos à procura da origem duma palavra, é muito útil termos datas concretas, tipo, no ano X eu já ouvia essa palavra. Portanto se nos indicares os anos, mesmo que seja aproximadamente, mais dois anos, menos três anos, já é uma grande ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

#### Certeza

De certeza, não se sabe. Apenas achei dois dicionários que considerassem *beque* uma palavra como um significado de *baseado*: O Houaiss e o Priberam. O Houaiss diz que não se estabeleceu ainda. O Priberam diz que vem do francês *bec*, que é bico.

Não confio muito no Priberam para etimologia, pois, pessoalmente já vi erros disso lá, e acho mais que tenham posto a palavra *beque* naquele espaço do que checado se ela tem a mesma origem.

#### Incerteza

Eu tentei achar a tal palavra “*beque*” em inglês. Não achei em nenhum dicionário confiável, mas achei em lugares de edição pública: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beak_(disambiguation)#:%7E:text=Beak%2C%20slang%20term%20for%20the%20drug%20cocaine), [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Beak) e [Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/beak). No Urban Dictionary, aparece inclusive como verbo. Como gíria aparece mais na fala e menos na escrita, não me parece irrazoável crer que *beak* realmente seja uma gíria para **cocaína**, mas não achei onde fosse gíria para maconha nenhures.

Mais evidência é [neste livro](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=XFIZR7YOkyYC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=%22gram+of+beak%22&source=bl&ots=Ve1RPlSw6L&sig=ACfU3U3M2WI3-nsou-CtieOl3H24LE2-rw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjn9bPc1eD4AhX_ObkGHT4VA9AQ6AF6BAgVEAM#v=onepage&q=%22gram%20of%20beak%22&f=false), onde se diz «People don't OD on half a gram of beak» (= «Ninguém tem *overdose* com um grama de cocaina»), de **2004**. Este livro está até na [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com.br/Brass-Helen-Walsh/dp/1841954845), com *preview*. A data indica que é gíria recente, recente o suficiente para não estar num dicionário. Também é fácil de encontrar outros exemplos pesquisando *"gram of beak"* ou *"grams of beak"* no Google. As aspas dizem ao Google que o que está nas aspas deve estar escrito no site, senão ele não mostra o site.

Talvez tenha acontecido influência da possível gíria *beak* em inglês que tenha criado a gíria *beque* em português. Note-se que *beck* é uma escrita alternativa de *beak*, mas não sei se é usada para a gíria, mas sei que tem uso.

Um contra-argumento é a diferença fonética das palavras, mas é comum um brasileiro falar errado uma palavra inglesa e essa pronúncia tornar-se comum, muitas vezes se baseando na escrita; a escruta da palavra *beak* é fácil de ser entendida como *béqui*. Por exemplo, no Brasil é comum dizermos *donut* algo como ***dâ**nãtch*, mas em inglês é ***dou**nât*.

Isto, porém, é só teoria e insuficientemente forte, pois, aqui não tratei dos seus primeiros usos reconhecidos em português nem explicitamente respondi a várias das perguntas óbvias, como «Por que *beque* é para maconha e *beak* é para cocaina?». E há a teoria, explicitada pela resposta cá do user11907, que *beque* vem de *bag*, com o suporte de que o [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bag#Noun) registra *bag* com o uso de *sacola para drogas*.

É engraçado que o Priberam talvez esteja certo, pois, *beak*, em inglês, vem do francês antigo *bec*.

Comment: Tive dificuldade em seguir a tua reposta a partir de "tentei achar a tal palavra 'beque' em inglês". Tentaste achar mesmo "beque"? Porquê "beak"? A pergunta sugere vir de "backwoods blunt", que existe realmente como designação de charuto de tabaco e canábis. "Back" é tipicamente pronunciado por brasileiros (e portugueses)  como "beque"; já "beak" tende a dar "bique" (como "leader" > "líder").

Comment: @Jacinto, tentei achar *beque* em inglês porque supus que o português *beque* fosse uma versão corrupta duma gíria em inglês semelhante. Eu tentei responder à diferença de pronúncia entre o inglês *beak* e o português *beque* dizendo que é comum um brasileiro pronunciar uma palavra em inglês errado, baseando-se na escrita dela. Ainda, se eu tivesse que falar a palavra *beak* e não soubesse inglês, diria como *béaque* ou *béque*.

Comment: Eu acabei por ver que era essa a tua ideia, mas ao fim do 1º parágrafo da "Incerteza" eu estava a coçar a cabeça. Dizes que procuraste "beque" e encontraste. Depois começas a falar em "beak"... E só depois de ir ver o que estava naqueles links (e eu prefiro ler a resposta sem ter de ir ao link) é que vi o que o que tu encontraste não foi "beque" mas sim "beak". E por que razão havia "beque" de vir de "beak" e não, como sugerido na pergunta, de "backwoods blunt", que, tanto quanto compreendo, é mais ou menos o mesmo que um beque?

Comment: @Jacinto, isso eu não sei, mas a transformação de *beak* para *beque* me parece mais suave do que a de *backwoods blunt* para *beque*, ao menos que *back* possa ser redução da gíria inglesa. Para isso seria bom ver as primeiras ocorrências de *beque* e variações em português, o que eu não fiz.